# Checking for duplicates within a numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, function, numpy, boolean

I am trying to code a function where it compares all the strings within a list and checks if they are equivalent to another with the checking statement.
I want the answer to be `True` if 2 or more strings are equivalent if not `False`. How would i be able to modify `checking` so that it works with
`numpy arrays` instead of a normal `list`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np 

def Checker(reader):
    checking = any(s for s in set(reader) if reader.count(s) > 1)
    print(checking)

reader = np.array(["cat", "dog", "cheetah", "giraffe", "monkey"])
reader2 = np.array(["cat", "dog", "cat", "giraffe", "monkey"])
reader3 = np.array(["cat","cheetah", "monkey"])

result = Checker(reader)
result2 = Checker(reader2)
result3 = Checker(reader3)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'
```

The result should list:

```
False
True
False
```

Comment: Very juicy question  senpai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY:

```
def Checker(reader):
    return np.unique(reader).size != reader.size
```